# Gibbs and Helmholtz Energies calculation for Heating an Ideal Gas at Constant Volume

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I am working on a problem in which 0.100 moles of an ideal gas undergoes several changes of state. One of the changes involves heating the gas from 20 $^{\circ}$C to 120 $^{\circ}$ at constant volume. The volume of the gas at this step is 4.0 L. The question asks to calculate the change in Gibbs Free Energy ($\Delta G$) and the change in the Helmholtz Energy ($\Delta A$) for the process.

I started from $dG = VdP - SdT$. The first term is not an issue as you can substitute $V=nRT/P$ and integrate. I am stuck with the second term. The same issue arises with $dA=-PdV - SdT$ as the first term is zero because it is a constant volume process but I am stuck again with the -SdT term.

I searched in quite a few books to see if there was an example like this one with no luck. All the problems involving $\Delta G$ or $\Delta A$ use isothermal conditions so the second term is never a problem.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entropy of an ideal gas is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas#Entropy). The Gibbs free energy for an ideal gas is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#Definitions). Try playing with these.

Comment: Please provide an exact word-for-word statement of the problem.